# Multiple Icons on status bar! How to disable this?

Tags: android

HI

In Bluetooth application I am noticing it is displaying multiple icons not number. I updated number of notification object, then it was displaying number and but also multiple icons.. how to disable this multiple icons?

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the .number on the Notification object shouldn't have that effect.

I think it is possible a bug in your code is calling NotificationManager.notify() multiple times. Try adding some logging when the notifications are sent.

Comment: Specifically, you will get multiple icons if you supply multiple notification IDs to `notify()`.